# Is there a function which creates a secondary dataframe of types for each entry in a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am currently working with a large dataset (over 1 million rows, 1000 columns) where the data is unclean - almost every column contains either some missing values or some free-text replacements where numerical entries should be found. Calling pd.DataFrame.dtypes therefore results in every column being 'obj' type, when in reality they should be a mixture of string fields and float fields. I am looking for a way of creating a secondary dataframe showing the data type for each individual entry. Consider for example the following dataframe:

```
       A  B
    1  ab 1.0
    2  2  cd
```

I would like to produce something along the lines of

```
       A   B
    1  str float
    2  int str
```

or the corresponding pandas dtypes. Due to the size of the dataset I would like to avoid multiple for loops and am looking primarily for inbuilt/vectorised solutions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) with `type`, but in real data obviously all values are strings (if DataFrame is created by `read_csv`):

```
df = df.applymap(type)
print (df)
               A                B
1  <class 'str'>  <class 'float'>
2  <class 'int'>    <class 'str'>
```

In real data if all values are strings and need string repr convert to numeric values is possible use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for non numeric to `NaN`s and [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for working with all columns:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))
print (df)
     A    B
1  NaN  1.0
2  2.0  NaN
```